# mongodb suddenly stopped to work

Tags: mongodb, centos, centos6.5

I've had mongo running for a while on my dev server running Centos 6.5 and mongo 2.6.4. 
But then I needed to install mysql for a different project and now suddenly mongo doesn't work.

I tried to re-install it and upgrade it to 2.6.5 at the same time. I've tried to start it and restart it:

```
# sudo service mongod restart
Stopping mongod:                                           [FAILED]
Starting mongod:                                           [FAILED]
```

Repairing it said I missed /data/db which I then created. The repair responds like this:

```
# sudo mongod --repair
2014-10-24T15:52:14.710-0400 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1182 port=27017     dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=myhost
2014-10-24T15:52:14.710-0400 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.5
2014-10-24T15:52:14.710-0400 [initandlisten] git version:     e99d4fcb4279c0279796f237aa92fe3b64560bf6
2014-10-24T15:52:14.710-0400 [initandlisten] build info: Linux build8.nj1.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2014-10-24T15:52:14.710-0400 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2014-10-24T15:52:14.710-0400 [initandlisten] options: { repair: true }
2014-10-24T15:52:14.726-0400 [initandlisten] repairDatabase local
2014-10-24T15:52:14.726-0400 [initandlisten] allocating new ns file /data/db/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/local.ns, filling with zeroes...
2014-10-24T15:52:14.843-0400 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /data/db/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/local.0, filling with zeroes...
2014-10-24T15:52:14.843-0400 [FileAllocator] creating directory /data/db/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/_tmp
2014-10-24T15:52:14.879-0400 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /data/db/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/local.0, size: 64MB,  took 0.017 secs
2014-10-24T15:52:14.897-0400 [initandlisten] finished checking dbs
2014-10-24T15:52:14.897-0400 [initandlisten] dbexit: 
2014-10-24T15:52:14.897-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2014-10-24T15:52:14.897-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2014-10-24T15:52:14.897-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2014-10-24T15:52:14.897-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2014-10-24T15:52:14.897-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2014-10-24T15:52:14.897-0400 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2014-10-24T15:52:14.897-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2014-10-24T15:52:14.897-0400 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

Starting it again, and fails.

did this:

```
#semanage port -a -t mongodb_port_t -p tcp 27017
Killed
```

Trying to enter the mongo shell responds with this:

```
# mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.5
connecting to: test
2014-10-24T15:59:40.243-0400 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2014-10-24T15:59:40.244-0400 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed
```

I'm out of ideas. Any suggestions?

Comment: What does your `mongodb.conf` look like?